# convert variable to text or string in R

Tags: r, postgresql

I read data from excel file to connect and use in postgreSQL. I could connect to database and need to query using the variables from excel file. This part is working fine.

I declara a variable from excel file say "school" which I need to use dynamically to query in database. below is my query

```
sid <- '500'
my_school <- RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = "SELECT * from school where school_id = sid ")
```

it works if I use "500" instead of sid but I need to use a dynamic variable.

the error I get is :

```
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  column "sid" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from school where school_id = sid 
                                                  ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "school.db_sid".
>
```

Could anyone look at this? Thanks.

Comment: I have used now : x <- '50'
                         my_school<- RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(conn = con,statement = paste("SELECT * from school where school_id = ", x, sep="") )
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: SELECT * from school where school_id = 50
                                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("SELECT * from school where school_id = %s", sid)
#[1] "SELECT * from school where school_id = 500"
```

Add quotation marks if appropriate:

```
sprintf("SELECT * from school where school_id = '%s'", sid)
#[1] "SELECT * from school where school_id = '500'"
```

Comment: I get Error: unexpected input .............. :(

Comment: I get this when i use quotation marks. 
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: SELECT * from school where school_id = sprintf('%f'

Comment: You are doing something wrong in transferring my answer to your actual use case. Why does the error message show `school_id = sprintf('%f'`? That's definitely not shown in my answer.